# Windows 7 / Ubuntu dual-boot and able to access windows partitions on both os

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I have a laptop running Windows 7 in partition c . I have 3 more partitions (D,E,F NTFS) with my data. I would like to install Ubuntu in dual-boot in other unused partition .Is it possible to access other windows partitions (D,E,F) as external drive in both os ?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu does have support for NTFS file system, so reading and writing is not a problem. But to access ubuntu partition from windows you need to use some extra software such as http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/ .

Comment: Thank you :) I don't want to use Ubuntu partitions with windows. Just need to access existing ntfs partitions with both Os

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Ubuntu has support for tons of filesystems, including NTFS. But I must warh you that Windows does not, so you won't be able to access your Ubuntu partition from Windows without formatting it.

Comment: Thank you :) I don't want to use Ubuntu partitions with windows. Just need to access existing ntfs partitions with both Os